# file match pattern R with several possible prefix and suffix

Tags: r, regex

I want to find any files that start with one of the possible prefixes and ends with one of the possible suffixes.

Here is the example:

1. file can start with "API" or "DB" or "S3" followed with one "_"
2. then the ID of the query is showing up plus a "." character
3. and the file name will end up with one of the "JSON" or "SQL" or "TXT"

I used the following code

```
filesPattern = "[DB|API|S3]_.*.[JSON|SQL|TXT]$"
LIST_OF_FILES  = toupper(list.files(dirProcess,
                                    pattern = filesPattern,
                                    ignore.case = T))
```

which is working somehow, but not accurately. first of all, I don't know how to force start with one of these prefixes. second the "." character before suffix is not checked. there are some other problems as well which I'm not sure if I defined possible prefix and suffix right?!

Finally, how I can get one file with an specific ID? for example:

these are my file names:

```
[1] "API_GPT.TXT"      "API_GPTR.R"       "DB_COUNTRY.SQL"  
[4] "DB_DECISIONS.SQL" "S3_BUCKET_LIST.R"
```

and I'm looking to get a file with ID = "DECISIONS".

Comment: Do you mean you need to find files whose file names start with `API` or `DB` or `S3` then having `_` and end with `.` and then `JSON`/`SQL`/`TXT`? `list.files` does not support PCRE pattern, as far as I know, I removed `perl` tag. Try `filesPattern = "^(DB|API|S3)_.*\\.(JSON|SQL|TXT)$"` pattern. One thing is unclear: do you want to exclude files like `S3__.SQL`?

Comment: Also, you do not need to use `toupper` if you use `ignore.case = T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[DB|API|S3]` is a bracket expression that matches a single char: `D`, `B`, `|`, `A`, `P`, `I`, `S`, or `3`.

You may use

```
filesPattern = "^(DB|API|S3)_.*\\.(JSON|SQL|TXT)$"
LIST_OF_FILES  = list.files(dirProcess, pattern = filesPattern, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(DB|API|S3)` - either of the 3 alternatives (`DB`, `API`, `S3` substrings)
- `_` - an underscore
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\\.`  - a literal `.` symbol
- `(JSON|SQL|TXT)`- either of the 3 alternatives (`JSON`, `SQL`, `TXT` substrings)
- `$`  - end of string.

You do not need `toupper()` as you are using `ignore.case = TRUE` argument that makes pattern matching case insensitive.

Comment: thanks. that is exactly what I was looking for. only one more question I did not understand your comment about PCRE pattern!

Comment: @MahdiJadaliha You tagged the question with `perl` tag. It makes no sense because 1) it is an R question, not related to Perl, 2) `list.files` does not support `perl` argument. `gsub`, `grep`, `grepl`, `sub` `regexpr`... they support `perl=TRUE` and then a PCRE regex egine is used to parse the pattern. `list.files` pattern can only be handled by the default TRE regex engine.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.